# Programs don't work on Vista and Server 2008

Tags: mfc, windows-vista, windows-server-2008, visual-c++-6, code-migration

Many, if not all, of my old VC++ 6.0 MFC apps don't work in Vista and Server 2008.  I had that migration was a problem, but now it's my problem  :(

How do I go about making these things work?  Is that possible?  I've searched, but is there some repository of knowledge on this subject?

edit:
Compatibility mode seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without recompiling, have you tried setting the compatibility mode on the program to Windows 98 or ME?

Answer (score 3):

There should be specific reasons why they don't work, and of course, what exactly does not work. Maybe you should break each issue into a separate question (maybe here at SO) and tell us exactly what kind of problems you have when you try to run them, and what is the code that makes those errors show up.

Without the details, it's too vague. There is no magic you can apply to make applications simply work just like that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a document available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BA73B169-A648-49AF-BC5E-A2EEBB74C16B&displaylang=en) that explains how to develop UAC compliant applications.